# Key Performance Indicators

Tags: macroeconomics

I am reading some book about strategic management.

First, I must tell you that my native language is not English.

My question is:

In the book, they divided **Key Performance Indicators** into three groups:

1) indicators of competence (or indicators of competency)

2) indicators of profitability

3) indicators of effectiveness (or indicators of efficiency)

Did someone heard about this distribution (division) of **KPI**s and what is the exactly translation of indicators?

I gave my best to translate correctly on English. If somebody heard of this division could you write the name of the books or articles on English where can I further read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Key Performance Indicators are important elements of a company that can be used to asess a firm's current core competencies and business model. They are based on of key result areas. Here is my interpretation of the three indicators and some examples (There are many more):

- Competency: A firm's business strategy and it's competitive advantage

  - Example: Retention, Value (Quality/Price), R&D Investment
- Profitability: A overall indicator of market performance

  - Example: ROI, Gross Margin, EBITDA
- Effectiveness: The implementation of a firm's strategy

  - Example: Market Share, Sales, New Market Segments

You may notice that the examples can be related to other indicators, because the indicators are a broad overview of the firm.

Comment: Do you know some book where can I read about indicators of effectiveness

Comment: Sadly, I don't have one that's electronic for you to reference but I do have a paperback one (it has no ebook to it) that I can use to send you a photo of information on KPI's